# HasMaxLength in EF OnModelCreating does not show an error when creating a string longer than expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I try to understand `OnModelCreating` in EF, I notice that there is an example on [Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) and this [website](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasmaxlength-method) say that:

> The HasMaxLength method is applied to a property to specify a maximum number of characters or bytes for the column that the property should map to.

In that case, I use the following code to try to figure out what will it do if I created a string that is larger than the max length:

```
namespace test
{
    internal class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSqlLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\XXXXX\Blogs.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        }
        #region Required
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .Property(b => b.Url)
                .HasMaxLength(5);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var a = new test.MyContext())
        {
            var b = new test.Blog() {Url="1234567890" };
            a.Add(b);
            //a.Database.EnsureCreated();
            a.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I set the `HasMaxLength` to 5 and the string is `123467890`, which is longer than 5. However, when I run the program, I noticed that it will not show an error and it will also not cut the data, while it saves the whole number into the database.

I am wondering why it will not show the error when I set a string larger than the max length.

Comment: it should result in a database field of type `nvarchar(5)`, but if that is not what the database field is, then you may not actually get an error

Comment: And you didn’t add the constraint after creating the database for the first time? The constraints are added to the database and if you add them later and don’t use a migration (or create a new database) anything you change in the model will not do anything, to my knowledge.

Comment: it looks like you are using SQL Server Express LocalDB; it's hard to confirm but it may just not support `nvarchar(X)` fields

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when You created the database, You didn't set the constraint **.HasMaxLength** in your **OnModelCreating** method (I tried it), adding it later. So, probably the best choice is to create your database again, or You can try to modify it issuing an SQL **ALTER TABLE** command, if You have pratice with that.